# How to rename multiple files with different names at once?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have several docx files (approximately 250 files) each one with a different name. I need to rename all these files so that the result has to be that each file name must be a consecutive number for the previous file, as follows:

*1.docx - 2.docx - 3.docx* - etc.

How can I do this using the command line in my Linux?

My biggest problem is that each file has a completely unreadable name.

For example:

*ÄÿÇä ÄùàÄàÜ ÄæÆë ÜÖÆà.docx*

Because these files were originally named in Hebrew and when the zip file was extracted the files were given illegible names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash mass rename files in folders and subfolders with sequential number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42607819/bash-mass-rename-files-in-folders-and-subfolders-with-sequential-number)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51369916/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
count=0; for f in *.docx; do mv -i -- "$f" "$((count=count+1)).docx"; done
```

If there was a chance that one of the original files was actually named with a simple number, like `3.docx`, then it is safer to move the files to some other directory at the same time that they are being renamed:

```
count=0; for f in *.docx; do mv -i -- "$f" "some/other/dir/$((count=count+1)).docx"; done
```

#### How it works

- `count=0`

  This initializes the variable `count` to zero.
- `for f in *.docx; do`

  This starts a loop with `f` being assigned to the name of each docx file in turn.
- `mv -i -- "$f" "some/other/dir/$((count=count+1)).docx"`

  This renames/moves the files.  `$((count=count+1))` tells the shell to increment the `count` each time.

  Under bash, `$((count=count+1))` can be simplified to `$((++count))`.
- `done`

  This signals the end of the loop.

Comment: Better `echo mv ...`  ... to a file `> renames.sh`.  Verify that those are good, then `. ./renames` to run them.  If a mess is made of this kind of thing, it's troublesome to undo. `mv` deletes destination files; if your code generates the same name twice somehow, you can lose a file.

Comment: E.g. what if we drop this code into a shell that happens not to recognize the `++` operator.

Comment: @Kaz That is a very good point.  I added `-i` to the `mv` command so that the problem would become immediately apparent before files were overwritten.  (My concern with `echo mv ... >a.sh`  and `. a.sh` is that it could lead to issues if any filename contained `"` or other shell-active characters.)

Comment: Yeah; don't echo to a file and run commands unless you really know what you're doing; but `echo` just to review the commands before removing the `echo` to finally run them is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
parallel --dry-run mv -v ::: *.docx :::+ {1..300}.docx
```

This will print commands to rename all files ending in `.docx` to consecutive numbers upto and including 300.

To actually run the commands (after inspection), remove the `--dry-run` option.

Comment: Thank you so much potong for having revealed the solution quickly, this command really works. However, for some reason, the last 10 files continue with the original name. Will you know why?

Comment: Perhaps because you have 310 `.docx` files? You can change the second file argument to `{1..1000}.docx` to cover upto a 1000 files, but the first file argument will limit the renaming to only those files.

Comment: No, actually the script worked fine until 231 and left 10 with the original name. Also I discovered that I should convert all these files to text (.txt), but I could not find a solution to do this with a bash. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I can only suggest you inspect the commands created by the `--dry-run` option.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
parallel mv -- {} {#}.docx ::: *.docx
```